# Facing ReferenceError while running tests with ScalaJS Bundler

Tags: scala, scala.js, scalajs-bundler

I am facing this issue when upgrading from `sbt-scalajs` *0.6.x* to *1.2.0* and the issue is:-

With `sbt-scalajs v0.6.26` (and `sbt-scalajs-bundler v0.14.0`), I have enabled the `jsdom` support for tests:

```
requireJsDomEnv in Test := true
```

And test suites are running fine.

But with `sbt-scalajs v1.2.0` (and `sbt-scalajs-bundler v0.18.0`), I have enabled the `jsdom` support for tests too:

```
requireJsDomEnv in Test := true
```

But this is giving me the following error:

```
[info] Writing and bundling the test loader
webpack:///./node_modules/@opentelemetry/api/build/src/platform/browser/globalThis.js?:21
exports._globalThis = typeof globalThis === 'object' ? globalThis : window;
                                                                    ^
ReferenceError: window is not defined
    at eval (webpack:///./node_modules/@opentelemetry/api/build/src/platform/browser/globalThis.js?:21:69)
    at Object../node_modules/@opentelemetry/api/build/src/platform/browser/globalThis.js
```

However, when I am removing the `requireJsDomEnv in Test := true` setting, the test suites run fine. I need to understand why this is happening? And how I can fix it?

I am using:

```
scala -> 2.13.3
Java -> OpenJDK 14.0.2
```

Comment: Could you upgrade one thing at a time, instead of making a relatively big jump in both sbt-scalajs and sbt-scalajs-bundler, to isolate the issue? From (0.6.26, 0.14.0) I would suggest the following upgrade path: (0.6.26, 0.14.0) -> (0.6.33, 0.14.0) -> (0.6.33, 0.18.0) -> (1.2.0, 0.18.0), running the tests between each independent upgrade.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the code, it looks like you are using node-js env with JSDom.

So to enable building you have to use **JSDOMNodeJSEnv()** for example: -

```
requireJsDomEnv in Test := true
jsEnv in Test := new org.scalajs.jsenv.jsdomnodejs.JSDOMNodeJSEnv()
```

Here the doc for more information:- https://www.scala-js.org/doc/project/js-environments.html